# NASLite 2 access over SMB from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, server-message-block

I have a NASLite-2 server that I can not connect with from Windows 7 RC over SMB.  It works fine from other Windows XP boxes on the network.  I can ping the NASLite-2 server from Windows 7 and even access the HTML based administration page.

I've tried changing the following in the local security policy:

```
Local Policies - Security Options

Network security: LAN Manager authentication level
Send LM & NTLM responses

Minimum session security for NTLM SSP
Disable Require 128-bit encryption
```

The strange thing is that I was running the Windows 7 Beta on one machine previously and had no trouble connecting to the the SAMBA shares after making the above mentioned changes.

Please forgive me for asking the question the question here but the ServerElements forum appears to unavailable and some of the response there are less than friendly.  I do not have any experience debugging SMB or enough experience to the nuances of with Windows 7 and networking.  A direct answer or any helpful advice on how to approach debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Windows 7 and used the policy changes in my question and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue with my NAS and windows 7.  i managed to get it working by mapping a network drive to the actual shared folder i was trying to access.